# EntityFramework ConnectionString utf8

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I want to add utf8 support to my Entity Framework database application (sql server 2008 r2)

I think I need to add the charset to the connectionString.

This is how my connectionString works (anonymized, of course)

```
<add name="MyContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyDatabase.csdl|res://*/MyDatabase.ssdl|res://*/MyDatabase.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=myserver\instancename;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I had a look at connectionstrings.com, but I found nothing regarding utf8.

I tried adding `charset=utf8`, but that doesn't do the trick.

```
 <add name="MyContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyDatabase.csdl|res://*/MyDatabase.ssdl|res://*/MyDatabase.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=myserver\instancename;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;charset=utf8;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Results in a System.Data.EntityException:
{"The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString."}
{"Keyword not supported: 'charset'."}

Question:
 **How do I set the charset to utf8 in the connectionString? Or is utf8 enabled by default?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usage of unicode is defined by variable or column type. `Char` and `varchar` are non-unicode and `nchar` and `nvarchar` are unicode (UCS-2).

There are also collations which define code page for `char` and `varchar` columns and the way in which strings are compared and ordered. Each database has a default collation and each column or variable can have explicitly defined other collation.

Character set is not configured by connection.

Comment: For the benefit of people reading this QA thread in 2020: SQL Server 2019 has support for UTF-8, and confusingly it uses `varchar` and `char` instead of `nvarchar`and `nchar` to store UTF-8 values. I don't yet know how this works with Entity Framework, as EF6 (and EF Core, I think?) always assume that `varchar` columns cannot store Unicode values.